# Is it safe to call SmtpClient.Dispose() in .NET?

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

I have a scenario where I need to send 100 emails in one shot (using a loop), but also I am not allowed to send 1 email per SMTP session.

Right now all 100 emails are sharing same SMTP session.

I was thinking that calling SmtpClient.Dispose() will take care of what I need. Please correct me if I am wrong.

So, basically 3 questions:

1. **Will SmtpClient.Dispose() take care of what I need?**
2. **If Yes, is it safe to Dispose() SmtpClient without affecting other services on the
   server?**
3. **If No, What would be the right approach to achieve what I
   want?**

**Sample Code:**

```
Private Shared Sub SendMail(ByVal MailServer As SmtpClient, ByVal body As String, ByVal Subject As String, ByVal FromEmail As String, _
                               ByVal ToEmailList As String, Optional ByVal AttFile As Attachment = Nothing)

    Dim message As New MailMessage

    Try
        message.From = New MailAddress(FromEmail)

        message.Subject = Subject
        message.IsBodyHtml = False
        message.Body = body
        message.Priority = MailPriority.High

        If Not AttFile Is Nothing Then
            message.Attachments.Add(AttFile)
        Else
            message.Attachments.Add(AttFile)
        End If

        MailServer.Send(message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New ApplicationException("SERVICE1.SendMail ERROR -- Error sending email [ERROR]:[" & ex.Message.ToString & "] " & vbCrLf & "To:" & ToEmailList & vbCrLf & "From:" & FromEmail & vbCrLf & "Subject: " & Subject & vbCrLf & "Body: " & body)
    End Try
    message.Dispose()
End Sub
```

And this is how the method is being executed:

```
 For Each Item In ItemListCollection
 m_MailServer = New SmtpClient(MailServerName)
 MailServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(MailServerUserName, MailServerPassword)
 SendMail(WeeklyMailServer, msgBody, msgSubject, MsgFromEmail, "xyz@abc.com", rptAttachment)
 Next
```

Comment: Could you show a portion of your code, including the loop?

Comment: updated with sample code

Comment: Sounds to me your service provider wants to stop you from abusing his service.  No, the Dispose() method is not a workaround for a contractual obligation you entered into with your service provider.  You'll need to negotiate another usage agreement with your provider instead.

Comment: It's a managed service, We have set the session limit to 15. That means we don't want to send more than 15 emails per smtp session. But it's a recent change and the code is old. We don't want to re-do the code.

Comment: If this is a commercial product, please look into using SendGrid or Amazon SES, you can send thousands of emails for next to nothing.

Comment: Not in my power @scartag. We need more security than features, we are using one of the most secured service and we have the ability to set the limit to 1000 emails per session but we do not wan't to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap it in a using statement and ensure that it is disposed when execution leaves the block. And you can call Send multiple times in a loop using the same SmtpClient.

```
Using client = New SmtpClient()

    For i As Integer = 0 To 99
        Dim message = New MailMessage()
        'initialization of whatever is needed
        ' message creation

        client.Send(message)

    Next
End Using
```

Comment: does that mean every single email being sent (all 100  emails) will create it's own SMTP session?

Comment: @Mihir No! they will all use the same instance we created at the top

Comment: So that's what I don't want. It will send 15 emails and than throw me error as we have set the limit to 15 emails per session.

Comment: @Mihir It's up to you to change the value to whatever u want.

Comment: that's what I am trying to say. We can change it to more but my network admin wouldn't do it. So I have to make change at the code level.

Comment: @Mihir You want to send 100 mails but only 15 per session, is that the issue?

Comment: Yes, whichever is easier 15 per session or even 1 per session is fine.

Comment: I suppose 15 emails/session requires some extra coding logic while 1/session seems to be an easier and faster approach.

Comment: @Mihir 1 per session is easier. just include the instantiation inside the loop instead.

Comment: Exactly that's what I was thinking and expecting from someone to validate my view. But again, do I need to call Dispose on SmtpClient?

Comment: @Mihir Yes you can call dispose without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Inside execution loop, you can enclose the code in a `Using` block. This will use a separate `smtpclient` for each email and will dispose / close it properly.

```
 For Each Item In ItemListCollection
   using m_MailServer as New SmtpClient(MailServerName)
     MailServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(MailServerUserName, MailServerPassword)
     SendMail(WeeklyMailServer, msgBody, msgSubject, MsgFromEmail, "xyz@abc.com", rptAttachment)
   end using
   Next
```